# How to show community articles to users based on custom field in user object?

Tags: community, knowledge, articles, partner, lightning-knowledge

I have few articles in my salesforce community.There are four standard visibility settings in knowledge object for articles:-

1. Visible in Internal app.
2. Visible to Customer.
3. Visible to Partner.
4. Visible in Public Knowledge Base.

Apart from these standard options I want to show some articles based on a custom field in user object.
Urgently need any ideas on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar type of requirement. I could able to achieve this through below steps:

1. Created 1 data category ex: Parent
2. Created 2 child data category : CH 1, CH 2
3. Assign respective articles to Parent > CH1 and Parent> CH2 data category respectively.
4. Created 2 permission sets by giving custom permissions to each child data category
5. Write Trigger to assign permission sets to customer portal users once specific fields meets the criteria.